# Jquery help, making collapsible sidebar for a vbulletin forum

Tags: jquery, sidebar, vbulletin

I'm trying to make a sidebar for my vbulletin skin that's expandable/collapsible.
Heres my code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".hide").click(function () {
            $("#sidebar").animate({ width: "0px", opacity: 0 }, 500);
            $("#sidebar").animate({ padding: "0" }, 500);
            $("#sidebar").css("margin", "0");
            $("#sidebar").hide;
        });

        $(".show").click(function () {
            $("#sidebar").animate({ width: "150px", opactiy: 100 }, 500);
        });
    });
</script>


<!--Sidebar Start-->
<table width="$stylevar[outertablewidth]" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>

        <td width="150" valign="top" class="page" id="sidebar" style="padding: $stylevar[cellpadding]px;">
            <a class="hide" href=#>YOUR CONTENT HERE</a>
            <a class="show" href=#>YOUR CONTENT HERE</a>
        </td>

</table>
<!--SideBar End -->
```

I want the sidebar to collapse completely, so it looks like it wasn't there.

Also I know using tables ain't great, but its the easiest way to do it with vbulletin.
Oh, and I plan on moving the .hide and .show out of the sidebar once its done, probably just to the left of it.

Last thing, you can view what I've done [Here](http://gfxscene.co.uk/vbulletin/?styleid=2)
Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the [extslide plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/7823/release) which defines `slideLeftHide()` and `slideLeftShow()`. It could be helpful to either use the plugin or just browse the source to see how they do it.

**edit**: they appear to do the equivalent of the following:

```
$(".hide").click(function(){
  $("#sidebar").animate({width:"hide", opacity:0}, 500 );
});
```

and

```
$(".show").click(function(){
  $("#sidebar").animate({width:"show", opacity:100}, 500 );
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate, had to edit it slightly to make it work
used
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $(".hide").click(function(){
  $("#sidebar").animate({width:"hide", opacity:0}, 500 );
});

$(".show").click(function(){
  $("#sidebar").animate({width:"150", opacity:100}, 500 );
});


 });
</script>

but yeah, thanks tonnes mate, i owe ya one